# Where are these empty anchor tags coming from?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm getting empty  tags in my [page](http://cubic-dev.asu.edu) that aren't in the page source, but are visible upon inspecting the element via firebug.  I've disabled javascript to see if that was injecting it, as well as disabling all add-ons.
Here is an excerpt from the page source, free of random `<a></a>`:

```
...
<div class="middle-content">
     <div class="asu_set_fixed_width">
      <div id="navbar">
       <div id="navbar-inner" class="clear-block region region-navbar">
        <div class="region region-navbar">
         <div id="block-menu-primary-links" class="block block-menu first last region-odd odd region-count-1 count-1">
          <div class="content">
           <ul class="menu"><li class="leaf first active-trail"><a href="/index" title="Home" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li class="leaf"><a href="/About_CUbiC" title="About CUbiC">About CUbiC</a></li>
...
```

and now examining with firebug with **javascript disabled**:
[image: firebug view with the annoying little buggers]
Same thing happens in Chrome as it does here in Firefox. Any thoughts on where these are coming from?

Comment: I'm confused.   You said you disabled JavaScript but you didn't say what the result was.  Point being:  Is this situation being caused by JS or not?

Comment: The problem persists with JS disabled, the results above are with no JavaScript running.

Comment: @CMike what I'm looking at is not empty.

Comment: @CMike this is what I see inside the `<a>` element, `<li class="leaf first active-trail"><a href="/index" title="Home" class="active">Home</a></li>` 
.

Comment: @CMikeB1:  See my answer.  JavaScript is not disabled.

Comment: Got it, simple syntax error and the browser was creating the empty <a></a> tags to try and compensate for the mismatched elements.  Next time I will use a validator, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validate your HTML.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fcubic-dev.asu.edu%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

- `end tag for "a" omitted`
- `start tag was here`
- etc..

The snippet of HTML in question is this *(I added line breaks)*:

```
<a href="#">
    <img id="cubic-header-newsletter-img" src='..' alt='..'.>
<a>
```

There should be an `</a>` at the end there instead of `<a>`.

Answer (score 3):

Line 195:

```
        <a href="#"><img id="cubic-header-newsletter-img" src='/sites/all/themes/asuzen/images/newsletter_pic.png' alt='Newsletter imgae, click here for newsletter'.><a>
```

I think you mean:

```
... newsletter'></a>
```

and not:

```
.... newsletter'.><a>
```

Comment: I found out where the unmatched 'a href' element was by following back where the empty tags appeared in firebug and then where they stopped opened up the source and found the missed end tag.

Comment: Excellent.  I should have caught that, especially after staring at it for any hour...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that in Safari's Error Console but it does not look like you've disabled all of your JavaScript.

This is an error I'm seeing:

*Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://cubic-dev.asu.edu/ from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/KiHrxGnVjLg?rel=0&controls=0. Domains, protocols and ports must match.*

**EDIT:**

Also, as stated by **thirtydot**, you must Validate your code.